# Create gravity form poll based on post types

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is there a way to create/update form poll fields based on a content type? For example, I've got a post type called `Candidate` and I'd like like to dynamically update a poll list when a new Candidate is added, or when one is removed.

The reason I'm looking for this is because I'm creating a voting mechanism for this client and they have requested that users see an image, the name, and brief Bio of who they are voting for. My idea is to tie in the names so that I can target a hidden Gravity Form poll on page so when the voter clicks, it updates the corresponding named checkbox.

I can of course add each Candidate one by one, and then add each candidate one by one in the form, but was hoping there was a way to do that in code. So far I haven't found much other than filters in the Gravity Forms Documentation.

To reiterate, my question here is not the frontend connection, rather how to dynamically update/add an option in a poll field in a form when content is created for a `Candidate` post type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution you're after is documented here:

> http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/gravity-forms/extending-gravity-forms/hooks/filters/gform_pre_render/

Probably a combination of solution examples #1 and #2 on that page will fit your needs? So -

1. Create a category of standard Wordpress pages (category name: "Candidates"), and the pages would contain the candidate information (bio, photo, etc).
2. In your functions.php file for your current theme, you'd add something like the following to pull out that category's worth of posts:

   ```
   // modify form output for the public page
   add_filter("gform_pre_render", "populate_checkbox");
   // modify form in admin
   add_filter("gform_admin_pre_render", "populate_checkbox"); 

   function populate_dropdown($form) {
       // some kind of logic / code to limit what form you're editing
       if ($form["id"] != 1) { return $form; }

       //Reading posts for "Business" category;
       $posts = get_posts("category=" . get_cat_ID("Candidates"));

       foreach ($form['fields'] as &$field) {

           // assuming field #1, if this is a voting form that uses checkboxes
           $target_field = 1;
           if ($field['id'] != $target_field) { break; }

           // init the counting var for how many checkboxes we'll be outputting
           // there's some kind of error with checkboxes and multiples of 10?
           $input_id = 1;
           foreach ($posts as $post) {

               //skipping index that are multiples of 10 (multiples of 10 create problems as the input IDs)
               if($input_id % 10 == 0) { $input_id++; }

               // here's where you format your field inputs as you need
               $choices[] = array('text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title);
               $inputs[] = array("label" => $post->post_title, "id" => "{$field_id}.{$input_id}");

               // increment the number of checkboxes for ID handling
               $input_id++;
           }

           $field['choices'] = $choices;
           $field['inputs'] = $inputs;
       }

       // return the updated form 
       return $form;
   }
   ```